# # symbol in cmakelists.txt

Tags: cmake, ros

I am learning ROS. The question looks silly but I am just a beginner.

```
find_package(catkin_simple REQUIRED)

# find_package(catkin_simple REQUIRED)
```

by introducing the # symbol, Am I making the command line as a comment.

an example in my cmakelists.txt I have the following lines

```
#Libraries
#cs_add_library (my_lib src/my_lib.cpp)
```

So I believe the first line is a comment
but what about the second line? Is it a comment too?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, the second line is a comment. From cmake's [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/manual/cmake-language.7.html#line-comment):

> A # not immediately followed by a Bracket Argument forms a line comment that runs until the end of the line: